# TextField Formatting in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I am trying to create a formatted SwiftUI TextField for an interest rate entry, I wanted the % to be appended to the end of the input string but this is causing an issue that the user cannot delete the inputed number.

here is my implementation:

```
var fieldView: some View {
    TextField("", text: $input)
        .frame(height: 48, alignment: .center)
        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        .onChange(of: input) { newValue in
            input = "\(newValue)%"
        }
}
```

view

Comment: `TextField("", text: $input, format: .percent)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just showing the % as a

```
Text("%")
```

next to your `TextField`? This seems to me like the easiest solution.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, that would cause formatting issues with the background / corner radius

Comment: That is the recommended solution though. Playing around with TextField contents while the user is typing is never a good idea. I'm sure the layout can be fixed as well.